# Вводное слово на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения

Tags: пунктуация

> Вводные слова и сочетания, стоящие на
> границе однородных членов или частей
> сложного предложения и относящиеся к
> следующему за ними слову или
> предложению, не отделяются от него
> запятой: Послышался резкий стук,
> должно быть сорвалась ставня. А.
> Чехов, Невеста. (Ср.: Послышался
> резкий стук. Должно быть, сорвалась
> ставня.)   
> [Грамота.ру.](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach2/)

Для меня этот пункт правила про вводные слова кажется каким-то мутным. Например, есть такие вводные слова, как *"а значит"*, которые в художественной литературе почти всегда стоят на границе и выделяются запятыми с обеих сторон. 
Одинаковое ли правило применяется в этих примерах ниже?

1. Если я иду быстро, значит(,) я тороплюсь домой.
2. Я шел быстро, следовательно(,) я торопился домой.
3. Я шел быстро, наверное(,) торопился домой.

Считается ли за грубую ошибку постановка запятой, если она там не нужна по правилу, процитированному выше?

Answer (score 5):

Суть этого пункта состоит в том, что вводное слово не выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если появляется двусмысленность:Послышался резкий стук, должно быть, сорвалась ставня. К чему относится "должно быть " как сомнение - сомнение, что послышался стук, или сомнение, что ставня сорвалась? Чтобы убрать двусмысленность, присоединим вводное к той части, к которой оно относится, т. е. уберём запятую.В Ваших последующих примерах двусмысленности нет, ясно, что относится ко второй, значит, ставим обе запятые.
1) Если я иду быстро, значит, я тороплюсь домой. 
2) Я шел быстро, следовательно, я торопился домой. 
А в этом есть:3) Я шел быстро наверное, торопился домой. Я шёл быстро, наверное торопился домой. Придётся выбирать один из вариантов. В таких случаях советуют перенести вводное в середину нужного предложения:Я шел быстро,  торопился, наверное, домой. Пунктуация делает предложение ясным, прозрачным по смыслу.

А насчёт вводных-союзов,это где такое есть? Первый раз слышу. Значит может быть вводным, глаголом ОЗНАЧАЕТ,может выполнять роль связки "это", но союзом...никогда. Наверное - вводное и наречие ВЕРНО, НЕСОМНЕННО( уж это он знал  наверно, т.е. несомненно).Должно быть - вводное и глагол - сказуемое. Но союз...

Comment: Кстати, в некоторых  из приведенных примеров можно поставить двоеточие или тире по правилу бессоюзных сложных со второй частью, обозначающей причину или следствие.
Послышался резкий стук: должно быть, сорвалась ставня
Я шел быстро: наверное, торопился домой
Я шел быстро - наверное, торопился домой

Comment: Согласна.Один из вариантов разделить части предложения и указать место вводного в них.

Comment: @Людмила, мне ваша версия кажется более правдоподобной, нежели версия @behemothus, так как никогда не слышал, чтобы вводные были союзами или хотя бы выполняли их роль.     
Если, например, в предложении первая часть выражает условие, а вторая начинается с вводного слова, то запятую после вводного ставить надо, так? *"Иду быстро — значит, тороплюсь домой"*.

Comment: Да, верно. Именно так.Здесь смысл прозрачен, расставлены все смысловые акценты с помощью пунктуации.

Comment: Тогда возникает вопрос: почему в правиле так радикально написано про ненужность запятой, если вводное относится ко второй части?

Comment: >так как никогда не слышал, чтобы вводные были союзами или хотя бы выполняли их роль. 

Не знаю, что вы имели ы ыиду, но все укаханные словая - могут быть собзами. Смотрите словари, хотя бы на грамоте.

Comment: Мне ктстати очень не ноавится употребление слова "версия" в отношение умозаключения, где нет ни единого предположения. Вам не нравится объяснение - это вагше право. Но это не версия, а законченное утверждение.

Comment: Потому что это Вы его отнесли ко второй части, а кто-то отнесёт к первой.Чтобы не извратить смысл,уточнить, нужно убрать запятую, отделяющую его от второй части, оставив первую, отделяющую от первой.Вы просто не вдумались в смысл "на границе", чтоб не нарушать границ.

Comment: Ну,  это же Грамота.ру. Там всегда отвечают радикально, будто истина в последней инстанции. Не хочу сказать ничего плохого, но их советы несколько раз уже оказывались неверными, филфак университета их забраковывал, ставя ошибку в контрольных.

Comment: Это _**словари**_. 
На Грамоту неча пенять, коли рожа крива.

Answer (score 1):

Это вопрос о сосуществовании старых (времен Розенталя) и новых норм.
Розенталь: Послышался резкий стук, - должно быть, сорвалась ставня (тире появляется как дополнительный знак, чтобы устранить двусмысленность).
Лопатин: Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня.
Словарь вводных слов: Послышался резкий стук, должно быть, сорвалась ставня (двусмысленности нет, так как обычно вводное слово стоит в начале, а не в конце конструкции, к которой относится).
Розенталь: Если я иду быстро, значит, я тороплюсь домой (значит - вводное слово).
Лопатин: Если я иду быстро, значит я тороплюсь домой (если... значит - двойной союз).
Розенталь: Я шел быстро, следовательно, я торопился домой.
Лопатин:Я шел быстро, следовательно я торопился домой (следовательно - союз).
Розенталь и Лопатин: Я шел быстро, наверное торопился домой (между однородными сказуемыми запятая после вводного слова опускается). 
Словарь вводных слов: Я шел быстро, наверное, торопился домой (двусмысленности нет, так как обычно вводное слово стоит в начале, а не в конце конструкции, к которой относится).
Все варианты написания на сегодняшний день допустимы.

Answer (score 0):

Валентин, правило не мутное, тут другое...
Сразу скажу, что основная обдасть применения данного правила - вводные обороты, а не части сложного предложения. 
В подоных же примерах самое сложно - разобраться с тем, чем именно является хитрое слово в начале присоединяемой части - вводным или союзом. Здесь во всех трех случаях я вижу союз или союзное слово, следовательно вопрос о запятых снимается. 
Будь здесь по мысли автора именно вводное слово (грамматика это формально позволяет), его вынужденно пришлось бы обособлять, неколько даже против правил, но иначе его нельзя было бы отличить от союза. 
Более подробно посмотрите [здесь](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.44). Другое дело, что я не вижу решительно никаких причин вводить аввтору подобный синтаксис, трактовка "наверное", "следовательно" и "значит" как союзов здесь вполне естественна и адекватно передаёт смысл.

Что же касается сочетания "а значит", то это неразрывное сочетание союза с вводным словом, под рассматриваемое правило этот случай не подпадает, и обообление всей конструкции вполне законно. Обратите, кстати, внимание, что это "а значит" невозможно перествить в другую часть предложения, т.е. это оборот как бы "не совсем вводный", со своими требования к пунктуации, что и находит отражение в обычном его обособлении.

Comment: Перешла по Вашим ссылкам. Это Грамота.ру, они ссылаются на Большой толковый словарь, значит на Ушакова, проверила по Ушакову - там только вводное.Откуда они взяли - не знаю.О каком словаре идёт речь?Кстати, уже не первый раз с этим сайтом, у меня к нему не всегда есть доверие.Иной раз так запутают - не разберёшься.

Comment: БТС на грамоте - это Кузнецова. Не слышал, чтобы он Ушакова плагиатил, могу быть не в курсе, но в любом случае, Ушаков - это почти вековая давность.
И не только Кузнецов, там еще Лопатин аналоничную вещь говорит.

Да, собствено, это и так видно, что в подобных примерах используются эти слова в роли союзов (союзных слов).

Насчет доверия к сайту. На эту тему можно говорить, но не в данном случае, когда "сайт" - всего лишь носитель инофрмации, не им созданной. Доверять или нет здесь можно конкретным словарям.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь пишет:
Примечание. Если между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, разделенными запятой, находится вводное слово, то в качестве дополнительного знака возможна постановка тире, чтобы показать, к какой из частей сложного предложения относится вводное слово, или чтобы подчеркнуть присоединительный характер второй части. Например: Злые собаки лаяли на задворках, не решаясь выбежать навстречу бричке, – должно быть, отучили их от этой привычки проезжие солдаты (Саянов).

Лопатин пишет:

§ 94. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения):

Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.);

Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня(Ч.).

Выходит, можно по-разному оформлять вводные на границе, по крайней мере частей сложного предложения?

Comment: Конечно, ведь разные знаки препинания могут выполнять одну и ту же роль