# Вводное слово между однородными членами или частями сложного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, однородные-члены

1. Все, наверное, читали правило Лопатина об отсутствии обособления вводных слов **на границе** однородных членов или частей сложного предложения.

§ 94. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, **не отделяются от него запятой** (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения): *Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, **должно быть** спешил на водопой* (Пауст.); *Послышался резкий стук, **должно быть** сорвалась ставня* (Ч.).

2. Мне даже попались интересные дискуссии на эту тему: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/Еще-раз-о-лосе-который-спешил-на-водопой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/%D0%95%D1%89%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13334/Вводное-слово-на-границе-однородных-членов-или-частей-сложного-предложения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13334/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

3. **Давно это было, и кое-что изменилось с тех пор.** К примеру, я бы не стала считать вводное слово "следовательно" необособленным союзом в таких конструкциях (здесь у вводного слова только функция союза, но оно обособляется).  В союзном соединении ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ также обособленное вводное слово (это указано в Справочнике).

В любом случае здесь нужны **ссылки на классические правила и на грамматику**, чтобы доказать свою точку зрения. **Но правила Розенталя и Лопатина противоречат друг другу в этой весьма важной теме.**

4. И вот что думает по этому поводу **Розенталь.**

Розенталь § 43. Запятая и точка с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении (п.3)  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=148

Если между двумя частями бессоюзного сложного предложения находится вводное слово, то ИНОГДА В КАЧЕСТВЕ ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОГО ЗНАКА ставится тире, чтобы показать, к какой из частей сложного предложения относится вводное слово, или чтобы подчеркнуть ДОБАВОЧНЫЙ, ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ характер второй части:

*Где-то стучит мотор, — **видимо**, поблизости находится мастерская.*

*Злые собаки лаяли на задворках, не решаясь выбежать навстречу бричке, — **должно быть**, отучили их от этой привычки проезжие солдаты.*

5. Тогда **варианты записи** предложения выглядят так:

**Розенталь:**

(1) *Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, **должно быть**, спешил на водопой.*

(2) *Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, — **должно быть**, спешил на водопой.*

**Лопатин:**

(3) *Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, **должно быть** спешил на водопой.*

**Современный вариант** (из Справочника):

(4) Лось шел скачками в сторону озер — **должно быть,** спешил на водопой.

Сравнить: Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит.

6. И вопрос: **Какой или какие варианты вы считаете правильными? Какие из них неприемлемы в современном правописании?**

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Тему назвали "мутной". Но наясность можно легко устранить, если считать, что вводное слово в качестве необособленного присоединительного союза может относиться **только к обособленным оборотам.**

Comment: Я доже хочу знать ответ на этот вопрос. Ответа два года нет, может, перезадать? Или Вы нашли ответ?

Comment: Этот вопрос раньше задавали (два раза), вот и нет ответов. Попробуйте сами задать, только в своей редакции. Полной ясности нет, да и откуда она возьмется. Может, лучше на Грамоте.ру задать.
 https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/Еще-раз-о-лосе-который-спешил-на-водопой 
   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13334/Вводное-слово-на-границе-однор..-членов-или-сложн.-предл.

Comment: Может, тогда Вы зададите вопрос на этот сайт? Я не щадам, потому что мне тупо не приходит код, необходимый для публикации вопроса

Comment: Но «Грамота.ру» упоминает в справочниках по пунктуации только вариант с одной запятой. Лично я использую вариант с одной запятой, с двумя и с двумя запятыми + тире. Когда как

Comment: Хорошо, я задам, но чуть позже.  Сейчас времени мало, да и на сайте много незакрытых тем.

Comment: Вы задали вопрос? Напишите, когда придет ответ

Comment: Я на форуме  его задам. Грамота.ру мне никогда не отвечает.

Comment: Кста-ати, Sharon, меня вот недавно кое-что заинтересовало. А где вы взяли у Лопатина вариант обособления вводного слова с левой стороны тире, а с правой стороны запятой (...— [вводное слово], ...)? Есть ссылка на Лопатина, где об этом говорится? Это я для себя спрашиваю.

Comment: Почему не отвечаете? Думаю, вы видели. Мне интересно, Лопатин где-то писал о том, что так можно выделять вводное слово?

Comment: Думаю, что видела, но ничего не поняла.  У меня: Лопатин:

(3) Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой. А два предыдущих примера у Розенталя.

Answer (score 1):

Если писать по-Леопольновому, то, мэм, только так:

> Лось шёл скачками в сторону озёр, должно быть спешил на водопой.

> Лось шёл скачками в сторону озёр — должно быть, спешил на водопой.

Мне 2-й вариант больше нравится, честно. Первый тоже хорош. А вот остальные — это некошачии варианты. Точка!

Ещё пример Леопольдо-оформления:

> Ты писать начал по-нерусски, Георг, по-видимому поскольку ты слишком английским увлёкся.

> Ты писать начал по-нерусски, Георг, — по-видимому, поскольку ты слишком английским увлёкся.

Ещё примеры:

> У меня сегодня болит сильно-пресильно спинка, т. к. мне сделали укол, следовательно я не смогу сегодня свои животоупражнения сделать-таки.

> У меня сегодня болит сильно-пресильно спинка, т. к. мне сделали укол, — следовательно, я не смогу сегодня свои животоупражнения сделать-таки.

> У меня сегодня болит сильно-пресильно спинка, т. к. мне сделали укол. Следовательно, я не смогу сегодня свои животоупражнения сделать-таки.

Comment: Чудненько! Контрольный вопрос: можно по 2-му варианту написать предложение с вводным словом "следовательно"?

Comment: Да. Ещё примеры!

Comment: Не надо колоться, ни к чему это. А почему во втором варианте единый знак?  Так душе угодно?

Comment: Там запятая для *т. к.*, а потом — тире и запятая к *следовательно*.

Comment: @Sharon Запятая закрывает придаточное с _т. к_.

Comment: Откуда такие правила?  Хочу закрываю, а хочу нет?  По блокам решайте, три предикативные основы.  По блокам получается только тире, а у вас все получается.

Comment: @Sharon См. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474472/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85 Придаточность с _т. к._ — это, блин, придаточность, а не отношения, чтобы их не обособлять со второй стороны.

Comment: Не знаю таких правил, я только для трех считать умею, блин.  Три предикативные основы!  И точка! Решайте блоками по Лопатину, тогда все будет обозначено четко.  Все ваши открывающие и закрывающие запятые.  И пока, пока!

Answer (score 0):

**ТЕОРИЯ**

Все задачи можно решить **методом блоков** **[по Лопатину](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)**

Но здесь же только **две предикативные** основы, какие блоки?! Это не имеет значения: метод блоков можно применить к любой  **сложной или осложненной** конструкции, если возникают проблемы **в пограничной зоне**.

Это ***БСП***, осложненное **вводным словом**. Два блока, вводное слово обычно относится ко второй части. Отношения логического предположения: **факт и вывод**.

Интонация **присоединительная**. В этом случае ставится **тире,** но при необходимости можно поставить **единый знак**.

**Единый знак** ставится для того,  чтобы показать, к какой из частей сложного предложения относится **вводное слово**, или чтобы подчеркнуть **добавочный** характер второй части:

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

**ЗАПЯТАЯ** (у Розенталя)

*Послышался резкий стук, / **должно быть,** сорвалась ставня.*

Присоединительные отношения, пауза не подчеркивается. Вводное слово относится ко второй части, это и так ясно.

**ТИРЕ**

(1) *Лось шел скачками в сторону озер — // **должно быть**, спешил на водопой.*

Присоединение, факт – вывод, пауза подчеркнута.

(2) *Послал он мне крест – // **значит**, меня он любит.*

Причинно-следственные отношения, пауза подчеркнута.

**ЕДИНЫЙ ЗНАК**

(1) *Где-то стучит мотор, — /// **видимо**, поблизости находится мастерская*.

Присоединение, факт – вывод, пауза особо подчеркнута.

(2) *Злые собаки лаяли на задворках, не решаясь выбежать навстречу бричке, — /// **должно быть**, отучили их от этой привычки проезжие солдаты.*

Присоединение, факт – вывод, пауза особо подчеркнута.

**Дополнение**

**Единый знак (три основы)**

*У меня сегодня болит сильно-пресильно спинка, т. к. мне сделали укол, **— /// следовательно,** я не смогу сегодня свои животоупражнения сделать-таки.*

Присоединение, факт – вывод, пауза особо подчеркнута.