# Нужна ли запятая перед тире в следующих предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Нужна ли запятая перед тире?
*Эта звезда в 1708 раз больше Солнца, а вторая, как уже и сказали(,) — в 2150 раз*.
*Код от сейфа хранится там, откуда не украсть(,) — в моей голове*.

А также интересует, нужно ли сохранять запятую в конце придаточного с *который*, как в конце придаточного? Например:
*Самый быстрый объект, который запустили в космос(,) — это крышка люка.*

Comment: Полный пример приведите, конкретный, будет проще ответить.

Comment: Буратино, я привёл 3 примера **конкретных**, в чем вопросы твои?

Comment: У меня нет вопросов, просто русский язык - контекстный. В нем пунктуация может зависеть от положения и обстоятельств сказанного по тексту. То есть предыдущее предложение может влиять на синтаксис следующего. В первом и втором случае может быть и так и так, а в третьем, наверное, вообще тире не нужно, только запятая.

Comment: Нет, тире там нужно, разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое, присутствует связка «это »

Comment: Интересный вопрос, если его рассматривать с позиции БЛОКОВ, А иначе трудно решить, когда сохраняются оба знака, а когда нет. Приходится обращаться к текстологии, к примерам из правил, но это ненадежный способ анализа. Задачи решены для конкретных примеров, а нам нужно решить свой.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [справочнику Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176):

> При «встрече» внутри предложения запятой и тире сначала ставится запятая, а затем тире: *История открытий, изобретений, история техники, которая облегчает жизнь и труд людей, — вот, собственно, история культуры (М. Г.); Это не вода плещет, меня не обманешь, — это его длинные вёсла* (Л.).
>
> В большинстве случаев каждый из этих знаков препинания ставится на собственном основании:
>
> *Увы! Моя шкатулка, шашка с серебряной оправой, дагестанский кинжал, подарок приятеля, — всё исчезло* (Л.) — запятая закрывает обособленное приложение, тире поставлено перед обобщающим словом после перечисления однородных членов предложения;
>
> *Его походка была небрежна и ленива, но я заметил, что он не размахивал руками, — первый признак некоторой скрытности характера* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения, тире поставлено перед своеобразным приложением к предшествующим словам, имеет присоединительный оттенок;
>
> *Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть, тире поставлено перед частью предложения, выражающей следствие.

---

Во всех ваших примерах запятая ставится, так как она закрывает придаточное предложение. Тире ставится на другом основании.

> 1. Эта звезда в 1708 раз больше Солнца, а вторая, как уже и сказали, — в 2150 раз.

Тире замещает пропущенную конструкцию, ясную из первой части предложения. Полная версия предложения могла бы выглядеть так:

> Эта звезда в 1708 раз больше Солнца, а вторая, как уже и сказали, больше Солнца в 2150 раз.

[Тема в справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93). Обратите внимание на пункт 5.

> 2. Код от сейфа хранится там, откуда не украсть, — в моей голове.

Тире стоит перед конструкцией, которая уточняет значение слова "там". [Тема в справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118).

> 3. Самый быстрый объект, который запустили в космос, — это крышка люка.

Тире стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым, как вы сами сказали в комментариях. [Тема в справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92).