# В каких сложных предложениях правильно обособлено вводное слово «должно быть»?

Tags: вводные-слова, сложное-предложение

В этих предложениях **разная постановка** знаков между частями сложного предложения:

1. Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000

*Николай Васильевич бросил на него возмущенный взгляд — **должно быть**, в свете происходящего упоминание законов физики показалось ему предельно циничным.*

2. Василь Быков. Бедные люди (1998)

Телефон опять прозвонил раз и второй, — **должно быть**, кто-то точно знал, что он дома, но Скварыш все равно не подошел к трубке, хоть и встревожился еще больше.

3. В. Г. Распутин. Новая профессия (1998)

*…показалось Алеше, что его все еще нет, **должно быть**, нельзя ни видеть и ни слышать, что, как в физической жизни происходит обмен веществ, произошел в нем обмен чего-то незнаемого.*

4. Марк Сергеев. Волшебная галоша(1971)

*Мальчики заметили, что палец на правой руке у нее перевязан, **должно быть** порезала.*

**По какому правилу** можно объяснить выбор знаков  при обособлении вводных слов, каким **справочником** лучше пользоваться? Есть ли информация по этому вопросу **на сайте Грамота.ру?**  Какое вы ставите знаки в таких предложениях? (Эти вопрос интересует не только меня.)

Спасибо.

Тема рассматривалась раньше [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462938/Вводное-слово-между-однородными-членами-или-частями-сложного-предложения#comment511958_462938](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462938/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment511958_462938)

Comment: Четвёртое точно неверно. Если есть глагол, то уже не оборот.