# О дополнительном тире после запятой перед вводным словом

Tags: вводные-слова, бсп

1. **[По Розенталю,  пункт 10(2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)**   перед вводным словом в качестве **дополнительного** знака в некоторых случаях ставится **тире**:

*Собака исчезла, — **наверное,** её убили* (Слепц.).

*Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — **должно быть**, хочет зажечь огонь* (Гл.).

2. Но такое объяснение **не кажется ясным**: когда вообще можно использовать дополнительный знак? Кроме того,  **тире** в этих предложениях (БСП) представляется **основным**, а не дополнительным знаком. К тому же **вводное слов**о на границе двух частей в свою очередь осложняет ситуацию.
3. Поэтому можно использовать анализ отношений **на стыке** двух синтаксических конструкций, как это делается при решении задач методом **блоков:**

(1) Если запятой или тире **недостаточно** (по различным причинам, они указаны у Розенталя), то  можно использовать **запятую и тире** как более сильный знак.

(2) Если же в этом нет необходимости, то ставится только **тире** или только **запятая.**

Выбор делается для **конкретного** предложения.

4. Как вы относитесь **к такому решению**?  Задачу можно решить для заданного предложения, а **обоснование (ссылку)** подобрать у Розенталя.

Comment: Мы же современным вариантом пользуемся: с левой стороны тире, с правой — запятая.

Comment: Не поняла,   Сочетание знаков запятая и тире, а как еще можно записать?

Comment: _Собака исчезла — наверное, ее убили._ Это современный же вариант обособления, почему спрашиваете?

Comment: А кстати, посреди предложения заглавные буквы разрешено ставить? Типа, следующее предложение вы пишите с больштй, но через запятую с другим. Так можно? Где говорится об этом?

Comment: Нельзя, Максим, это у меня точка так выглядит. Значит, Розенталя отменили, а почему?  Кто разрешил? "Собака исчезла, — наверное, её убили".  Или автор свое предложение исправил?  Если не можем объяснить, то худ. тексты начинаем править?

Comment: Никто ничего не отменял. Этот вариант обособления не его, а, как вы сказали здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462938/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F, — Лопатина.

Comment: А. вот вы о чем.  Тогда принимаем такое решение. (1) Худ. тексты не правим.  (2) Свои тексты оформляем так,  как считаем нужным. (3) Объясняем по Розенталю или Лопатину, кто подойдет.