# Запятая или тире (вводные слова в СПП)?

Tags: пунктуация

Верны оба варианта?

> Он в скором времени пришёл, возможно, когда меня не было дома.

> Он в скором времени пришёл — возможно, когда меня не было дома. (Этот вар., по-моему, лучше, т. к. он сразу паузу, в отличие от 1-го, показывает-таки.)

Как я понимаю, этот вариант ложн.

> Он в скором времени пришёл, возможно когда меня не было дома.

А здесь?

> Что-то раззвучало на улке, может быть упал столб-шест.

> Что-то раззвучало на улке — может быть, упал столб-шест.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Он в скором времени пришёл — возможно, когда меня не было дома*** — думаю, лучше тире и что [7-й пункт](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137) не подойдëт, т. к. там были примеры, где обстоятельства в главной части не было, — им являлось придаточное; здесь же обстоятельство уже есть, а придаточное дополняет дополняет другое обстоятельство. Второй вариант действительно ложный;

***Что-то раззвучало на улке — может быть, упал столб-шест*** — современный вариант обособления вводного слова.

---

Если в главной части обстоятельства не будет, пишем:

***Он пришёл, возможно, когда меня не было дома*** — [7-й пункт](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137) отлично подходит, обстоятельство единственное — придаточное;

***Он пришёл — возможно, когда меня не было дома*** — длинная пауза перед вводным словом, акцент на главной, а не на придаточной.

Comment: «Что-то раззвучало на улке, может быть упал столб-шест» — этот вар. 100-процентно правильный.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Тоже, по этому вопросу (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462938/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), можно. Вводное слово относится к следующей части, не отделяясь от него запятой. Но лучше юзать современный вариант.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Ну что?

Comment: Да, мне современный вариант тоже по душонке.